# How can I do this without having to import the tables one by one?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have around 400 tables in a database. I want to import all the tables from the database except the tables named Table398, Table 223, and Table399.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve through `import-all-tables`

import command in Sqoop and by specifying the `exclude-tables` option with it as follows-

```
sqoop import-all-tables

--connect –username –password --exclude-tables Table398, Table 223, Table 399
```

Hope this will help!!